# How to keep changed status of CheckBoxList?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know the title is vague, so I'll fully explain here my problem..

So, I'm running VB.net 3.5. I have a dynamic list of server names, and I want to put them in a `CheckBoxList`. The list is populated and, using that same list, I make a graph of the performance for each server listed. I want to be able to check and uncheck the checkboxes representing servers and, when I lick an update button, it'll create a new graph and graph only the servers that are still checked. I noticed that the page still loads before the button click is handled, so the `CheckBoxList` will repopulate itself before being able to read the current `CheckBoxList`. Does anybody have any input on this?
This is my load. And I populate my checkboxlist inside ShowView()

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
    If _myQSVar.Count = 0 Then
            Calendar1.SelectedDate = Date.Now.Date.AddMonths(-6)
            Calendar2.SelectedDate = Date.Now.Date
        End If
        tbFromDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()
        tbToDate.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()
        lstControls = New List(Of System.Web.UI.Control)
        ShowView()
    End If
End Sub
```

I load my checkboxlist with a simple for loop

```
For each one As String in ServerList
   chkboxList.Items.Add(one)
Next
```

And I wanna try to preserve the checkboxlist values when I do an event handler for an update button.

```
Private Sub btnUpdateGraph_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateGraph.Click
'insert code
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your code. Its probably because with every page load you are rebinding. Its a lot easier for everyone to help you if they can see your code to point out what may be causing your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you populating the checkboxlist on form.load? If so make sure you checking for if Page.ispostback. Load the checkboxlist only if its not a postback.  This will make sure the page(and the checkboxlist) is not  reloaded when you click.

Also, please do not lick update buttons. They dont really like that!

Comment: Riiiight. They probably wouldn't like me licking the update button.... And, I populate the checkboxlist inside the block of the page.load when I check for if it's not a postback.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are binding CheckboxList at PageLoad Event. Just place the code inside the given code block:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
// Bind your Checkbox List here
}
```

This will bind your checkboxlist only in case if the page loads first time, not after any postback.

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: So I tried just a simple refresh of the page to see if it would at least keep the values of the CheckBoxList the same, and it didn't. Poo.

Comment: Can you please check the Checkboxlist property "EnableViewState". It should be set to true.

Comment: Just checked, it's defaulted to True.

Comment: Are you sure, you are trying to bind the checkboxlist inside the code block that i wrote above? Because a checkboxlist will loose all of its values if it bind itself again and again on every page load. The above code ensures that the checkboxlist will be bound only once (i.e. the first timeload)/

Comment: Yeah. In my Page_Load(), I have if check if it's not post back, and then run chkbosLst.DataBind(). But whenever I refresh, it's still able to get into the code block..

Comment: Ofcourse, it will go to codeblock... Because you are just doing Refresh (not the postback). Look if you run the page for first time, it will execute and go inside the if block to bind the checkboxlist. Now if you refresh the page or press F5 then still the page is running first time, so it will go again to the codeblock (as there is no postback event triggered yet). Try it through button click event. Is it still loosing values on button click ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. Anyway, so, running the code, fixed a small error. It now doesn't go in the code block of the page_load. However, when I try to get the previously saved checkboxlist, it doesn't pull it correctly. Correct me if I'm wrong, but would this be the correct way of doing it? 

chkboxlist = CType(form1.FindControl("chkboxLst"), CheckBoxList)

Comment: You Can directly access the checkbox list using its ID. why you need to find the control to access it. Its a server control and available at code-behind using It's ID.

Comment: I was trying something out and was using that. But, point being, I'm still not getting the previous checkboxlist.